# Sessions with AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp() Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, azure-active-directory, session-cookies

I'm trying to understand something here. Currently I have implemented a web app that would take a single sign in using Azure AD and authenticating the user to whatever in AAD using the code below.

## Startup.cs

```
// Other Configurations

services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

Configuration["AzureAd:Domain"] = domain;
Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"] = tenantID;
Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"] = clientID;
Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"] = clientSecret;

services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration, "AzureAd")
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(Array.Empty<string>())
    .AddDistributedTokenCaches();

services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
});

//Other Configurations
```

I'm trying to add a idle time, as seen above, to let the user know (this will most likely be done in the front end/Razor page) that if they're idled for about a min and they will be logged out. My question is how can I detect that session is going to be expired in the front end or what could be the best way to handle this situation? I've been in a rabbit hole for sometime and I'm tired of seeing Bugs Bunny asking me what I'm doing. I hope I made sense on the question. TIA

Comment: Session expire because of idle. You need to remember user last input timestamp to calculate the expire time.

Comment: Yes that is true but how can I detect that in the front end? I'm clearly overlooking something or it is screaming in my face but I can't seem to see it

Answer (score 0):

You could reference this small example to count down idle left time using javascript.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    // Set the idle expire time 
    leftTime = 30;

    //Decrement the left time counter every second.
    setInterval(timerDecrement, 1000);

    function timerDecrement() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = leftTime;
        leftTime--;

        //reset Timer when on below events.
        window.onload = resetTimer;
        window.onmousemove = resetTimer;
        window.onmousedown = resetTimer;    // catches touchscreen presses as well
        window.ontouchstart = resetTimer;   // catches touchscreen swipes as well
        window.ontouchmove = resetTimer;    // required by some devices
        window.onclick = resetTimer;        // catches touchpad clicks as well
        window.onkeydown = resetTimer;
    }

    function resetTimer() {
        leftTime = 30; 
    }

</script>
```

Testing:
[image]

Comment: In other words there's no way to communicate with session directly but this will act like a session. Did I understand that correctly?